# How to share a post on a friend wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium-mobile

Graph API and feed API are deprecated and the latter was replaced by the Share Dialog API which only allows to publish an individual story or an Open Graph story to the user's own timeline.

I'm developping with titanium appcelerator. How i should post on a friend wall ?

Isn't this possible anymore ?!

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer possible to post on a friend's wall via Share Dialog or the Graph API.

Also: the Graph API is not deprecated.  :)

Answer (score 0):

a workaround was to make an URL with parameters :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption 
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

and use the openUrl() method to open it on browser.

Comment: this doesn't have the post-to-friend feature as well. :)